# Subgroup of Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$.

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

I have doubt about subgroup of $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$.

**1)** Are they $\operatorname{Gal}(L/M)$ for $M/K$ a sub-extension of $L/K$ ? Or is it $\operatorname{Gal}(M/K)$ if $M/K$ is Galois ?

**2)** If subgroup of $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ are $\operatorname{Gal}(L/M)$, does $$\operatorname{Gal}(L/M)\leq \operatorname{Gal}(L/K)\iff M/K\text{ sub-extension of }L/K \ \ ?$$

($A\leq B$ mean $A$ subgroup of $B$).

**3)** If subgroup of $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ are $\operatorname{Gal}(M/K)$, does
$$\operatorname{Gal}(M/K)\leq\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)\iff M/K\text{ sub-extension of }L/K \ \ ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory: If $L/K$ is Galois, then there is an inclusion reversing bijection between subgroups of $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ and intermediate fields $F$ such that $K \subset F \subset L$.

Note that $[L:L^H]=|H|$ for a subgroup $H$ and furthermore this extension is Galois so $\operatorname{Gal}(L/L^H)=H$ where $L^H$ is the intermediate field fixed by $H$.

As for your second part, this is true for subgroups due to the inclusion reversing bijection. If $\operatorname{Gal}(L/M)=H$ and $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)=G$ then $M$ is precisely the fixed field of $L$ under $H$ and similarly for $K$. Since $K$ is fixed by $H$ as well (since $H \leq G$) then $K$ must be a subfield of $M$ as well. Furthermore, if $H$ is normal in $G$, then $M/K$ is also a Galois extension.